# Can you explain the performance of a (Bluetooth) antenna?

Tags: signal, bluetooth, antenna, pcb-antenna

I have got this pcb with a Bluetooth antenna and the electrical engineer who did the job gave me this chart : [image: this antenna graph]

My questions :

- what does decibel loss means in reality ? My guess : the antenna is supposed to emit at power 100% but there are some losses in the pcb and the actual signal strengh is of 100-x%, hence a loss of x%. Correct ?
- At the Bluetooth frequency range, my antenna is -13db. Is that good or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter S11 (aka [return loss](http://www.antenna-theory.com/definitions/sparameters.php)) is a measure of how accurately the antenna "looks like" 50 ohms. A perfect return loss scenario is -infinite dB but anything lower than -10dB is likely to be acceptable in most circumstances.

If you want a more detailed explanation note the following: -

[image]

Where,

[image]

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_loss) wiki page where I stole the picture formula. It's also related to VSWR: -

[image]

Image stolen from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave_ratio) wiki page.

Comment: stupid follow up question : if I want to know how much my body absorbs the antenna signal, is the formula  Power emission = Power reflected + Power absorbed + Power emit_beyond_my_body ?
or is it Power absorbed = Power reflected ?

Comment: If you are up close to the antenna you are in the near field and in the NF a proper EM wave has not formed so you can't base any calculations on power levels. If you are beyond the near field, your body receives a tiny fraction of the transmit power with nothing measurable at the transmit antenna. As for how much the body absorbs versus how much travels thru and beyond I have no idea but it will certainly be freq dependent with absorption being max at 2.45 GHz.